# Understanding Linker Map File (MS Visual Studio 2005)

Tags: dictionary, linker

All -

I'm trying to understand the first section of the Map file produced by the MS Visual Studio 2005 linker.  I know it has something to do with memory sections, but can someone help me decipher it?

```
Timestamp is 4b4f8d2b (Thu Jan 14 14:31:23 2010)

Preferred load address is 00400000

Start         Length     Name                   Class
0001:00000000 0028b752H .text                   CODE
0002:00000000 000001b4H .idata$5                DATA
0002:000001b4 00000004H .CRT$XCA                DATA
0002:000001b8 00000004H .CRT$XCAA               DATA
0002:000001bc 00000004H .CRT$XCC                DATA
0002:000001c0 00000004H .CRT$XCZ                DATA
0002:000001c4 00000004H .CRT$XIA                DATA
0002:000001c8 00000004H .CRT$XIAA               DATA
0002:000001cc 00000004H .CRT$XIC                DATA
0002:000001d0 00000004H .CRT$XIZ                DATA
0002:000001d8 00025288H .rdata                  DATA
0002:00025460 00000004H .rdata$sxdata           DATA
0002:00025464 00000004H .rtc$IAA                DATA
0002:00025468 00000004H .rtc$IZZ                DATA
0002:0002546c 00000004H .rtc$TAA                DATA
0002:00025470 00000004H .rtc$TZZ                DATA
0002:00025478 0000007cH .xdata$x                DATA
0002:000254f4 00000028H .idata$2                DATA
0002:0002551c 00000014H .idata$3                DATA
0002:00025530 000001b4H .idata$4                DATA
0002:000256e4 00000542H .idata$6                DATA
0002:00025c26 00000000H .edata                  DATA
0003:00000000 000f070cH .data                   DATA
0003:000f0720 001f1280H .bss                    DATA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/mapfile.aspx) is a good reference.  I've been looking for this myself, as MSDN apparently provides no information whatsoever about them.

Comment: Link is dead but it is still here: https://web.archive.org/web/20110830095842/http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/mapfile.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Those are just the object sections that need to be merged into image sections. Read up on PE and COFF if you're not sure what that means.

Comment: Thanks.  Turns out wikipedia has some good reading on the subject: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable

Comment: The spec is better. http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/platform/firmware/PECOFF.mspx