# Where the variable stored (data segment or heap or BSS) according to the variable's address?

Tags: c, linux, macos, process, heap-memory

A little similar with [Where are static variables stored (data segment or heap or BSS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516902/where-are-static-variables-stored-data-segment-or-heap-or-bss),but not the same one.

Now I get a other process's variable's address like:0x10fb90,where is this variable stored(data segment or heap or BSS), could i get the location just from the process's pid and the variable's address?

I am working on osx using obj-c and c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options.

### 1. Use [`objdump`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump)

Something like

```
objdump -x a.out | grep YOUR_VARIABLE_ADDRESS
```

### 2. Use gcc's map option to generate a [map file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068632/understanding-linker-map-file-ms-visual-studio-2005)

Compile something like this in gcc

```
$ gcc -o foo.exe -Wl,-Map,foo.map foo.c
```

and now

```
$ grep YOUR_VARIABLE_ADDRESS foo.map
```

Both these methods will show your variable's location, if at all the address you supplied exits.

**PS**: The link I've added for the `map file` shows an example map file generated by Visual Studio linkers, but the format is typically similar in most of the map file formats generated by various linkers

Comment: Is there any way programming using c to achieve the target?

Comment: @AlanGame Try invoking `objdump` from within a C program using `system` function

Comment: I forget to specify that the target variable is belong to other process not myself.

Comment: @AlanGame Do you mean other program? Then just replace `a.out` with the other program's name

Comment: Did you try `objdump` by replacing a.out with the other program's name?

Comment: It is not work well,under OSX and iOS, the DATA section, stack and heap's start address may be randomized per execction.

Comment: What makes you search for variable addresses instead of variable names?

Comment: Because i want to change other application's variable, change other process's memory not my process's. So i do not know the variable's name.

Comment: @AlanGame if the variable addresses are randomized in every exxecution then your question "finding an address 0xXXXX..." itself becomes void

Comment: Actually,i have found the address by searching the process's memory space according to the changes between the variable's value.